# Issues with @RequestMapping & JSON String

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have the method signature as :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveMapping", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
 public void saveProducts(@RequestBody Product[] products)
```

I am trying to test it using chrom postman utility and passing below json as raw , json type:

```
{
type: "RING",
productId: 2251,
},
{
type: "SHOE",
productId: 2252,
}
```

but every time I am getting :

```
           "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
```

Please help

Comment: is it a typo, or there are no enclosing outer braces arond your json data?

Comment: Add `Content-Type: application/json` header to postman preset?

Comment: Like the previous comments, and how you are sending the Data? your `handler` method is working only with `post`

Comment: This is what the request header contains:
Accept
application/json
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: And I tried passing json with and without [] and it gave me same result –

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Content-type http header is setted to text/plain instead of application/json.